# IOException on Directory.Move after using process of that directory

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET Core project that does some actions on the MongoDB.
One of which is checking the current mongod version, and then changes the name of the bin directory (this directory holds the mongod.exe file).

For some reason, if i dont do Thread.Sleep after checking the mongod version, i cannot do the directory rename because i get the following exception:

> System.IO.IOException: Access to the path 'C:\MyMongo\bin' is denied.

Please note in the GetMongoVersion method that i get the "### EXITED ###" message before "Returning version" message.

GetMongoVersion method:

```cs
public Version GetMongoVersion(string path)
{
    Version version = null;
    var mongoServicePath = Path.Combine(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration["MongoServicePath"], "bin");

    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WorkingDirectory = mongoServicePath,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            FileName = Path.Combine(mongoServicePath, MongodFileName),
            Arguments = "--version",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.Exited += (sender, args) => _log.Fatal("### EXITED ###");
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        while (version == null)
        {
            var line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            if (line != null && line.StartsWith("db version"))
            {
                var fullVersion = line.Split(' ')[2].Substring(1);
                var major = int.Parse(fullVersion[0].ToString());
                var minor = int.Parse(fullVersion[2].ToString());
                version = new Version(major, minor);
            }
        }

        _log.Fatal($"Returning version: {version}");
        return version;
    }
}
```

RenameDirectory method:

```cs
public bool RenameDirectory(string currentName, string newName)
{
    try
    {
        Directory.Move(currentName, newName);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems possible that the process that you are spinning up actually spawns other processes from the `bin` folder that haven't yet exited.

Comment: seems unlikely, as mongod --version also works when its the only file in the directory

Comment: ... unless it's spinning up a second instance of itself... I've seem daemon products that do exactly this. Still a longshot though.

Comment: any suggestion on how to check it?

Comment: Not directly, but you could probably establish if this is a mongo specific issue or simply some sort of race with the filesystem by trying something with a different executable.

Comment: Could also be the virus scanner...try disabling it. Sometimes it hangs around and scans a directory

Comment: @ChristianSauer ohh wow havent thought of that.. though i cant really disable the anti virus ;/

Comment: @TomerSomething can you exlcude the dir?
Try it at a computer '(vm) without scanner - if it works it is most likely this. Had this type of roadblock, too.

Comment: @ChristianSauer i spoke with IT, they will be able to do this in an hour, after which i will update if it worked.

Comment: @ChristianSauer well i dont know what to say.. im doing the same thing multiple times. The first 3 times its working, after that it fails with same error. Before i deactivated anti-virus, it was failing on the first time. No idea what to do..

Comment: @TomerSomething I am somewaht.--speechless, too. Just use a sleep. It's guly but works most likely